# Schema.org ranking vs rating

Tags: schema.org, ranking, rating

I would like to use schema.org markup on my site.  There are rating options/values to use but I need ranking.  Only thing I can think to do is use rating of 10 stars = ranking of 1, rating of 9 stars = ranking of 2, etc. I was using search in google and was directed here to post question.  If there is someone from google or familiar with schema.org values please comment.  Best option would be to add ranking as a feature of schema.org.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you give more details about your case? What kind of ranking is this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no a ranking property in any of the schema items but rankings are just ordered lists, they specify the relationship of things between them in a list.

You can use `https://schema.org/position` to set each item position in an ordered list `https://schema.org/ListItem` simulating a ranking.

Comment: Excellent idea. Thank you. Will use position and list item.